# How to access another db from a stored procedure in db2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I want to query a table in another db from within a stored procedure in db2. For example, I am connected to db_a1, and call a stored procedure from within which I need to connect to a table in db_a2.

Is this possible in db2 ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Read the manual about _federation_.

Comment: Mustaccio is spot on. (In fact he should post that as an answer.) I have supported databases where developers did this exact thing (including federation to databases both local to the same instance and remote from the instance).